# Splitting specific characters from sequence in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a series of strings that look like the following (to show some examples):

```
S1+2S2  
S2  
2S3+S4  
S1+S2
```

and I want to extract only the species numbers from these strings. That is, ONLY the numbers following the "S" characters. So after splitting the Strings (or extracting from them?) I would want it to yield:

```
1 2  
2  
3 4  
1 2
```

Is this something that can be done using one or two lines in Java? Or would this be a multi-step series of loops, splitting the sequence once, then again, then again as I currently have it?

Thanks guys!

Comment: You could use "S+" as separator string for StringTokenizer

Comment: Do you just want the numbers following `S`?

Comment: @Prince. That is clearly specified in the question, if you read it clearly.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit. Are you reading from a file?

Comment: @Prince. I think you have mistaken me for OP. Please check the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This passes your test:

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SandboxTest {


    @Test
    public void testInputEqualsOutput() {
        String input = "S1+2S2\n" +
                "S2\n" +
                "2S3+S4\n" +
                "S1+S2";
        String output = processInput(input);
        assertEquals("1 2\n" +
                "2\n" +
                "3 4\n" +
                "1 2", output);
    }

    private String processInput(String input) {
        return input.replaceAll("\\d?S", "").replaceAll("\\+", " ");
    }

}
```

The `processInput` method replaces all "S"s that may have a digit in front of them with "".  Then it replaces all + symbols with a space.

Comment: This may fail for one thing. You are not extracting what is needed, but you are removing everything else that is not needed. Now, that not needed part is something you don't know. So, you won't get correct result for any other string, that doesn't match the exact format as specified in the example.

Comment: IMO you're critiquing the implementation instead of its correctness.  How do you know that matters?  It passes the test.  If he has another input and expected output this fails on, I'll modify my test to pass that.

Comment: Exactly. that is what I'm talking about. You would need to modify the regex for other strings that comes. And that defeats the purpose of Regex in general.

Comment: [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) If he has additional requirements he should say them.  As it stands, this works for what he needs.

Comment: Well, he has clearly specified his requirement. He want the digits after `S`. And you haven't given him that.

Comment: What input would this fail on? I'll modify the test for that case.

Comment: Rather than replacing all other characters, you should extract the digits which is preceded by `S`. So, the regex required is `S(\\d+)`, and then get the `group 1`. This will cover all the strings.

Comment: Your current regex may fail on input where you have something other than `digit` before the `S`. Like in: - `-_S2`, it will return :  `-_2`

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I wanted! All I needed was the numbers!